# Can we control our computer's USB port?

Tags: driver, power-electronics, usb-device, c++, usb-host

what i want to do is : I want to connect a USB fan to my laptop and through programming want to turn on and turn off the fan. Is it possible to do so?

Please post your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Not usually, no.

Comment: You should be able to disable usb ports through your device configuration.  I don't know if there's an API which will let you program this,but it wouldn't suprise me.  In any case, the question is OT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your goal when you aren't experienced in electronics is to use an **Arduino**. This tool will do the bridge between your computer and the fan and make everything secure. 
You need to do the following:

1. Buy an Arduino (or get one) and attach by USB to your computer
2. Attach your fan (assuming it has only 2 pins to connect) to the right pin output 5V and GND of the Arduino.
3. Profit ! You can turn it off by disconnecting the Arduino

If your fan does not spin it means that you need more power. But normally a computer fan of 12V will spin with the power that a USB port can deliver.

The Arduino is a programming tool, so you can do more complex things with it. Look for "PWM" if you want to control the speed of the fan.

Answer (score 1):

It is not usually possible to turn on and off power to a USB port from a program running on the computer.  Usually, the port is powered whenever the computer is powered.  Some laptops might be able to do it by abusing the power-saving features, by putting the USB controller into a low power state, but that'll turn all the USB ports off, not just one.

What you could do, is build your own usb-powered and usb-controlled fan.  The easiest approach would be a microcontroller with USB-serial support.  You'd probably also need a mosfet to drive the fan. If the microcontroller has a PWM output, you could probably even make it a variable-speed fan.